# How to get distinct count along with different conditions

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, distinct

My data looks like this,
[image]

I've 4 distinct Result category: Normal, Mild, Moderate and Severe

I want to get count of patients for each categories and
in case of severe category, I want to further divide it into more categories based on its corresponding Result value (e.g., Severe_500_to_599,  Severe_600_to_699, Severe_700_to_799 and severe_>800) and then get the count of these sub categories.

So my Results should look like this,
[image]

Currently I'm taking individual count by putting the specific condition,

```
select count(distinct SOURCE_PATIENT_ID)
from Table1
where RESULT_CATEGORY = 'SEVERE' and RESULT_VALUE_STANDARDIZED between '1100' and '1199' and RESULT_UNIT <> 'MG/DL';
```

Is there any way to get all the results in one single query?

Thanks!

Comment: Use "SELECT DISTINCT ResultCategory, SUM(ResultValue) OVER(PARTITION BY ResultCategory) AS SumResultValue, COUNT(PatientID) OVER (PARTITION BY ResultCategory) AS CountPatientID FROM Results". NOTE: I dont know your table name and this code is not tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window function with `QUALIFY` clause can be used here to divide data sets into individual buckets and then get single value out of those bucket.

Following query -

```
with data (patient_id, result_category, result_value) as (
select * from values 
(110,'Normal',35),
(123,'Normal',135),
(111,'Mild',151),
(191,'Mild',199),
(112,'Moderate',211),
(113,'Severe',501),
(115,'Severe',500),
(144,'Severe',723),
(146,'Severe',801)
)
select 
case 
    when result_category = 'Severe' 
        AND result_value between 500 and 599 
    then 
        'Severe Bucket (500-599)' 
    when result_category = 'Severe' 
        AND result_value between 700 and 799 
    then 
        'Severe Bucket (700-799)' 
    when result_category = 'Severe' 
        AND result_value between 800 and 899 
    then 
        'Severe Bucket (800-899)' 
    else 
        result_category
end new_result_category, 
sum(result_value) over (partition by new_result_category) patient_count 
from data
qualify row_number() over (partition by new_result_category 
order by patient_id desc) = 1;
```

Will give result as below -

| NEW_RESULT_CATEGORY | PATIENT_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| Mild | 350 |
| Moderate | 211 |
| Severe Bucket (700-799) | 723 |
| Severe Bucket (500-599) | 1001 |
| Normal | 170 |
| Severe Bucket (800-899) | 801 |

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest the underrated `grouping sets`?

```
with cte as

(select *, case when result_value between 500 and 599  then 'Severe Bucket (500-599)' 
                when result_value between 700 and 799 then  'Severe Bucket (700-799)' 
                when result_value between 800 and 899 then 'Severe Bucket (800-899)' 
           end as breakdown
 from data)

select coalesce(result_category,breakdown) as category,
       count(distinct patient_id) as patient_count 
from cte
group by grouping sets (result_category,breakdown)
having coalesce(result_category,breakdown) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Union all to combine your query´s

```
select  'SEVERE-599' as ResultCategory,
        count(distinct SOURCE_PATIENT_ID)
from Table1
where RESULT_CATEGORY = 'SEVERE' and RESULT_VALUE_STANDARDIZED between '500' and '599' and RESULT_UNIT <> 'MG/DL'
Union ALL
select  'SEVERE-699' as ResultCategory,
        count(distinct SOURCE_PATIENT_ID)
from Table1
where RESULT_CATEGORY = 'SEVERE' and RESULT_VALUE_STANDARDIZED between '600' and '699' and RESULT_UNIT <> 'MG/DL'
```